# How do I create a task with required fields using the rally ruby api?

Tags: ruby, api, rest, rally

I'm trying to create a task using the following sample code:

```
    fields = {}
    fields["Name"] ="test"
    fields["Workspace"] = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.42/workspace/1234567.js"
    fields["Project"] = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.42/project/1234567.js"
    fields["Owner"] = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.42/user/1234567.js"
    fields["Estimate"] = '0.25'

    @rally.create(:task, fields)
```

When run I get the following errors:

```
Error on request - https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.42/Task/create.js - 
{:errors=>[
  "Validation error: Task.Project should not be null", 
  "Validation error: Task.WorkProduct should not be null"
], :warnings=>[
  "API status is Deprecated and will become Not Supported on 2014-05-08", 
  "Ignored JSON element Task.Project during processing of this request."
]}
```

The errors seem odd. On one hand they indicate the api is ignoring Task.Project in the JSON but then there is a validation error that Task.Project is null.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

A Task cannot be created without being associated to a Work Product (i.e. a Story or Defect). A Task inherits its Project from the Project of the Work Product. So that's why the Project setting is being ignored. You'll need to associate the Task to a Story or a Defect when creating it:

```
fields = {}
fields["Name"] ="test"
fields["WorkProduct"] = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.42/hierarchicalrequirement/1234568.js"
fields["Owner"] = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.42/user/1234567.js"
fields["Estimate"] = '0.25'

@rally.create(:task, fields)
```

Give that a try and it should work for you.